# How to pass event to another event

Tags: c#

I want pass event to another event,now I use function to do that.

Can C# pass event like b.WriteEvent += a.WriteEvent ?

If I had a lot class,and just want pass argument to above class.

I want write like : a.event += b.event. b.event += c.event

Instead of a lot no use method.

Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        a.WriteEvent += MainWrite;
        b.WriteEvent += a.WireFunction; // Now I use
        //b.WriteEvent += a.WriteEvent; <= Can I use like this ?
        b.WireFunction("some str");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void MainWrite(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    public event Handler WriteEvent;
    public void WireFunction(string str)
    {
        WriteEvent(str);
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    public event Handler WriteEvent;
    public void WireFunction(string str)
    {
        WriteEvent(str);
    }
}

public delegate void Handler(string str);
```

Comment: You can use the same event handler for multiple events : `b.WriteEvent += MainWrite;`

Comment: No. Not sure why you're even asking; the compiler gives an error message. Is the message not clear? Also, why are you even trying this?

Comment: The reason is my MainClass can't call ClassB. Thanks

Comment: Hi Michael. You should not leave your questions open for too long. If there is a correct answer you may accept it or write one on your own if you think you can provide better info :)

Answer (score 0):

**Fact:
You cannot provide an event that subscribes to an event.**

All delegates (events, actions or funcs) ar multicast delegates in C#.
That means you can subscribe to an event multiple times.
In order to subscribe to an event you have to provide an action or a function. (I use the term function instead of method because we may provide a lambda)

What follows is snipped that subscribes all subscribers of Event1 to Event2.
I believe this is what you intend to do.

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public event EventHandler Event1;
   public event EventHandler Event2;

   public SomeClass()
   {
      Event1 += Subscriber1;
      Event1 += Subscriber2;

      var subscribers = Event1.GetInvocationList();

      if(subscribers != null)
      {
         foreach(var subscriber in subscribers)
         {
            EventHandler realSubscriber = (EventHandler)subscriber;
            Event2 += realSubscriber;
         }
      }

      Event1(this, EventArgs.Empty);
      Event2(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }

   public void Subscriber1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 1 invoked");
   }

   public void Subscriber2(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 2 invoked");
   }
}
```

Creating an instance of the SomeClass will print:
*Subscriber 1 invoked

Subscriber 2 invoked

Subscriber 1 invoked

Subscriber 2 invoked*

EDIT:
I tried to move the logic to an extension method and also to a normal utility method. Both did not work very well because events are `null` when they have no subscribers. Passing an event without subscribers would then result in the same behaviour as if `null` was passed. For now, this is the best I could come up with.